# How do I auto expand/auto select added node when adding nodes to ExtJS 4.2 treepanel?

Tags: extjs, tree, state, extjs4.2

The sample code provided is for an ExtJS 4.2 treepanel. If you click the buttons, an Ajax call to PHP adds a node to the tree.

The tree starts out with all folders closed.

I'm wondering how to approach auto selecting the added node, and auto expanding its parent if necessary to show the selected, newly added node. Currently adding a node and refreshing the data causes the tree to return to its initial state, which is all folders closed.

If the user happens to expand some nodes before adding the nodes, I want to remember the tree state, and also auto select the newly selected node, expanding the parent if necessary.

I tried this plugin but it just did not work:
https://github.com/AlexTiTanium/ExtJsStatefulTree

Sorry for the multiple data files at the end. I could not figure out how to update JSON in PHP.

```
function setData(data, scope) {
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'data.php',
        method: 'POST',
        params: {
            data: data
        },
        success: function() {
            scope.store.getData(onGetData, scope);
        },
        failure: function() {
            alert('failure');
        },
    }, scope);
}       
function onGetData(store, scope, records, success) {
    //alert('here');
};
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
        title: 'Tree Refresh Example',
        itemId: 'treeComp',
        width: 300,
        height: 350,
        store: new SampleTreeData(),        
        rootVisible: false,
        listeners: {
            afterRender: function() {
                this.store.getData(onGetData, this);
            }
        },
        tbar: ['->', { 
            xtype: 'button', 
            text: 'Add Banana',
            value: "Banana",
            margin: '0 30 0 0',
            listeners: {
                click: function(comp) {
                    setData(comp.value, this.up('treepanel'));
                }
            }
        }, { 
            xtype: 'button', 
            text: 'Add Cabbage',
            value: "Cabbage",
            margin: '0 30 0 0',
            listeners: {
                click: function(comp) {
                    setData(comp.value, this.up('treepanel'));
                }
            }
        }, { 
            xtype: 'button', 
            text: 'Add Yogurt',
            value: "Yogurt",
            listeners: {
                click: function(comp) {
                    setData(comp.value, this.up('treepanel'));
                }
            }
        }, '->'],
        renderTo: 'content'
    });        
});

Ext.define('SampleTreeData', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    autoLoad: false,
    autoSync: false,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : '',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: ''
        }
    },
    root: {
        expanded: true
    },  
    getData: function(callBack, scope) {
        var store = this;
        store.proxy.url = 'data.php';
        store.load({
            scope : scope,
            callback : function(records, operation, success) {
                if (Ext.isFunction(callBack)) {
                    callBack(store, scope, records, success);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../../ext-4.2.2.1144/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../../ext-4.2.2.1144/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="refresh1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="SampleTreeData.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: #89E5BD;">
    <div id="content" style="margin: auto; width: 500px; height: 500px;"/>
</body>

<?php
$logref = fopen('data.log', 'w');
fwrite($logref, "Entered script.\n");

if(isset($_POST['data'])){
    fwrite($logref, $_POST['data'] . "\n");
    if($_POST['data'] == 'Banana') {
        $newdata = file_get_contents("banana.json");
    } else if($_POST['data'] == 'Cabbage') {
        $newdata = file_get_contents("cabbage.json");
    } else if($_POST['data'] == 'Yogurt') {
        $newdata = file_get_contents("yogurt.json");
    }
    file_put_contents("data.json", $newdata);
    echo 'success';
}else {
    fwrite($logref, "getData\n");
    $data = file_get_contents("data.json");
    echo $data;
}
fclose($logref);
?>

---------------- initial tree data --------------
[{ 
        text: "Tree Root", 
        expanded: true, 
        children: [ 
            { 
                text: "Fruits", 
                children: [ 
                    { leaf:true, text: "apple" }, 
                    { leaf:true, text: "orange" } 
                ] 
            }, 
            { 
                text: "Vegetables", 
                children: [ 
                    { leaf:true, text: "carrot" }, 
                    { leaf:true, text: "beet" }
                ] 
            }, 
            { 
                text: "Dairy", 
                children: [ 
                    { leaf:true, text: "milk" }, 
                    { leaf:true, text: "cheese" } 
                ] 
            } 
        ] 
    }]

----------- data if Banana is clicked -----------
[{ 
        text: "Tree Root", 
        expanded: true, 
        children: [ 
            { 
                text: "Fruits", 
                children: [ 
                    { leaf:true, text: "apple" }, 
                    { leaf:true, text: "orange" }, 
                    { leaf:true, text: "banana" } 
                ] 
            }, 
            { 
                text: "Vegetables", 
                children: [ 
                    { leaf:true, text: "carrot" }, 
                    { leaf:true, text: "beet" } 
                ] 
            }, 
            { 
                text: "Dairy", 
                children: [ 
                    { leaf:true, text: "milk" }, 
                    { leaf:true, text: "cheese" } 
                ] 
            } 
        ] 
    }]

----------- data if cabbage is clicked --------
[{ 
        text: "Tree Root", 
        expanded: true, 
        children: [ 
            { 
                text: "Fruits", 
                children: [ 
                    { leaf:true, text: "apple" }, 
                    { leaf:true, text: "orange" } 
                ] 
            }, 
            { 
                text: "Vegetables", 
                children: [ 
                    { leaf:true, text: "carrot" }, 
                    { leaf:true, text: "beet" }, 
                    { leaf:true, text: "cabbage" }
                ] 
            }, 
            { 
                text: "Dairy", 
                children: [ 
                    { leaf:true, text: "milk" }, 
                    { leaf:true, text: "cheese" } 
                ] 
            } 
        ] 
    }]

----------- data if yogurt is clicked -------
[{ 
        text: "Tree Root", 
        expanded: true, 
        children: [ 
            { 
                text: "Fruits", 
                children: [ 
                    { leaf:true, text: "apple" }, 
                    { leaf:true, text: "orange" } 
                ] 
            }, 
            { 
                text: "Vegetables", 
                children: [ 
                    { leaf:true, text: "carrot" }, 
                    { leaf:true, text: "beet" } 
                ] 
            }, 
            { 
                text: "Dairy", 
                children: [ 
                    { leaf:true, text: "milk" }, 
                    { leaf:true, text: "cheese" }, 
                    { leaf:true, text: "yogurt" }
                ] 
            } 
        ] 
    }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you required to reload the tree ? Are you saving the data on the server side on each ajax ? Depending on the answers, I would approach this problem differently.

1. You are not required to reload. The data belong to the current user, but you have to store its state.
   a) Simply do not reload. Have ExtJs adding the node to the tree, and you can keep it expanded. Have your ajax call updated the server side data, but do not reload the tree. Drawback: if you have a bug, the server and client side are not guaranteed to be identical.
   b) Have ExtJs adding the node to the tree, and you can keep it expanded. Don't save to the server during operation, but save the new structure when finished editing.
2. You are required to reload, because the tree could change on the server while the user is editing (like concurrent updates between to independent users).
   a) I think in this case, you could send the tree state to the server and getting it back from there, by adding `expanded: true` to the nodes.

For instance when banana is clicked let the server return:

```
[{ 
    text: "Tree Root", 
    expanded: true, 
    children: [ 
        { 
            text: "Fruits", 
            children: [ 
                { leaf:true, text: "apple" }, 
                { leaf:true, text: "orange" }, 
                { leaf:true, text: "banana", expanded: true } 
            ],
            expanded: true
        }, 
        { 
            text: "Vegetables", 
            children: [ 
                { leaf:true, text: "carrot" }, 
                { leaf:true, text: "beet" } 
            ] 
        }, 
        { 
            text: "Dairy", 
            children: [ 
                { leaf:true, text: "milk" }, 
                { leaf:true, text: "cheese" } 
            ] 
        } 
    ] 
}]
```

1. b) You can reload the tree from the server, but you save it's state locally. You could use the beforeload event to store the state in an object, and then the load event to expand the nodes ( maybe other events are better suited ).

Comment: I will be dealing with scenario 2, because there could be multiple users adding objects to the tree. I don't for now expect real-time updates to the tree for objects other users add, unless I add a node and I reload the tree, so I get any new objects others have created in the meantime. Is there a way to prevent the tree from doing a hard refresh on reload, meaning don't collapse everything and just update existing tree with new nodes? Even if this involves an override of the treepanel class, I would be willing to give it a go if you think its doable.

Comment: I think expanded: true should be sufficient, isn't it ?

Comment: The thing is, in my situation, when I add a node, I'm not sending the tree data to the server. I'm posting the data to create an object. So then I once again query to get the tree data, but because I did not save the tree data, there is no way to save which nodes should have expanded true. But I wonder if there is a way to save something to local storage, that saves the tree node's expanded state, and then just walk down the tree after reload. Of course that still results in initially closing all tree nodes and then re-opening as necessary. Trying to avoid that.

Comment: @Greg I completed my answer. I would not use localstorage, but simply in a variable. When you use the best suited event, the nodes should never show all collapsed.